# Unable to work with response from an API call with Promises in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am working with a react app without Redux or anything similar. 
For network requests I'm using axios. Everything, just doesn't.
I push a group of print job ids and a name with axios as JSON to the backend, everything does fine and the group is created. But I should get as a response the created group from the backend (works on postman).

The code looks like this:

```
createPrintGroup = (assignments = [], name) => {
    return axios.post(this.URL.concat('add'), {
        print_jobs: map(assignments, 'printjob_id'),
        name: name,
    });
};
```

an example request looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "TestGruppe3",
    "print_jobs": [140, 141]
}
```

and the response in postman works:

```
[
    {
        "createdPrintGroup": [
            {
                "print_group_id": 37,
                "stl_solid_group": "data/print-groups/37",
                "name": "TestGruppe3",
                "date": "2019-05-19T22:00:00.000Z"
            }
        ],
        "assignedPrintJobs": [140,141]
    }
]
```

now what I'm trying to do is the following:

```
printgroupAPI.createPrintGroup(markedAssignments, printgroupName)
 .then(res => console.log("Data from Res: ", res.data[0])).catch(err => console.log("SHIT: ", err));
```

But the code just jumps over the .then and .catch part and continues I never reach one of these chained calls.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use `console.log("Data from Res: ", res.data)` without the `[0]`?

Comment: @MickVader same it never gets printed but the db changes and if i go to another view I can see the group which was created

Comment: Can you add a `.finally(console.log(res.data));` after the catch and see if it fires?